# Specify file_path while triggering AWS codebuil

Tags: github, webhooks, aws-codebuild

I have created AWS codebuild pipeline. It triggers automatically whenever I push to the Master branch.
Now, I want to trigger it only when something is changed in Dockerfile. Below is my project structure:

```
casestudy
|
|
|->Docker->Dockerfile
|-> Infrastructure -> infrastructure-files
```

Below is the screenshot of codebuild webhook filter:
[image]

If I push something to Dockerfile, the build is not getting triggered.

Kindly note that if I remove the file_path filter the build triggers with every push on the master branch.
My code is placed on GIthub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want file_path = `docker/Dockerfile`

or perhaps, to prevent things like otherdir/docker/Dockerfile from triggering it, file_path = `^docker/Dockerfile`

If you go through the Github web interface and view the repository's webhooks (Settings->Webhooks) and click "Edit" next to the webhook created by CodeBuild and then scroll down to the bottom where it says "Recent Deliveries", by clicking the "..." next to one of those you can actually see the request sent to the webhook.  You will see in there the list of files modified by the commit, and they will not have a leading slash (e.g. "docker/Dockerfile")