# How to properly set an AWS Codebuild conditional build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

In AWS Codebuild's build project I am trying to set my FILE_PATH "Don't start a build under these conditions." However, I can't get it to work.

how would I go about setting the proper regex that the aws build project will recognize?

**info**

***Source Provider:*** GitHub

***Event type:*** Push

***Commits to this file should not trigger a build:***  README.md

I don't believe amazon is following the traditional regex pattern but here is a picture what I currently have (I based it on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/github-webhook.html) where they have `^buildspec.*`). Also this is just an example I want to get working before I move on, the real requirement is to list multiple files to be ignored by my build project.

[image: what I've tried]

P.S. I tried read this post but still could not figure it out. [Specify file_path while triggering AWS codebuil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039773/specify-file-path-while-triggering-aws-codebuil)

Comment: "on the documentation" - what documentation? You haven't provided any reference link.

Comment: @Marcin I was just stating that `^buildspec.*` is what was used in the AWS documentation. If you want said documentation though, I'll ad it to the post.

Comment: I couldn't anchor the location to the "documentation" link so I'll just tell you here. The location in the documentation is the fourth example in the Filter GitHub webhook events (console) section.